# Polite ways to ask for quotation agreement

Tags: word-choice, word-order, phrase-usage

To ask my client if he is agree with the price and time I quote for my service, I often say:

- Please let me know if you are ok with this price.
- Please let me know if you are comfortable with my quotation.

Are these sentences ok for business?

Please suggest me any other ways to ask.

Comment: As @YosefBaskin points out, giving your clients the upper hand isn't a good thing to do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s asking for business advice.

Answer (score 2):

Your polite words may be **giving away your power**.

- See article in [Forbes magazine: 10 Ways You Could Be Giving Away Your Power (Without Even Realizing It)](https://www.forbes.com/sites/amymorin/2017/03/25/10-ways-you-could-be-giving-away-your-power-without-even-realizing-it/#6dcbcf9f6123)

Both of your phrasings would invite me to suggest a lower price. Am I okay? No. Comfortable? No.

More positive wording include: "Please let me know if you have any questions on my quotation" and "When would you like me to start?"

If I am selling, and I wait for all clients to be okay with my prices and comfortable with them, that's waiting not selling. Look up 'sticker shock' -- many clients end up buying products and services after initially reacting to the price with shock, neither okay nor comfortable. I want them buying while thinking "The price is high, but the value is good."

As friends, of course, I can ask you, are you okay and comfortable with the idea?